# $\forall\varepsilon>0$ there exists a subset $F$ of $[0,1]$ that is closed, contains only irrational numbers and $|F|>1-\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, outer-measure

I have proved the following result and I would like to know if I have made any mistakes (in particular, I am not sure that the set $F$ I have built is necessarily closed). Thank you.

"Let $\varepsilon >0$. Prove there exists a subset $F$ of $[0,1]$ such that $F$ is closed, every elements of $F$ is an irrational number and $|F|>1-\varepsilon$"

(NOTE: $|\cdot|$ denotes the outer measure)

Let $r_1,r_2,\dots $ be the sequence that contains every rational number in $[0,1]$, $\varepsilon >0$ and consider the set $F:=[0,1]-\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(r_k-\frac{\varepsilon}{4\cdot 2^k},r_k+\frac{\varepsilon}{4\cdot 2^k})$. Then $F$ is closed, being the complement of the open set $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(r_k-\frac{\varepsilon}{4\cdot 2^k},r_k+\frac{\varepsilon}{4\cdot 2^k})$ in $[0,1]$, contains only irrational number since we have taken away all the rational ones, and $|F|\geq |[0,1]|-|\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(r_k-\frac{\varepsilon}{4\cdot 2^k},r_k+\frac{\varepsilon}{4\cdot 2^k})|\geq (1-0)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}=1-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>1-\varepsilon$.

Comment: $|F|\geq |[0,1]|-|\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(r_k-\frac{\varepsilon}{4\cdot 2^k},r_k+\frac{\varepsilon}{4\cdot 2^k})|=(1-0)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}$ is false. You have to replace equality by $\geq $ and then everything would be fine.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy corrected, thanks!